# Как передать значение value из input1 в value input2

Tags: php, html

Есть несколько инпутов с предустановленными значениями(берутся из БД):

```
<form>
<input name="1" value="А" disabled>
<input name="2" value="Б" disabled>
<input name="3" value="В" disabled>    
<button>редактировать</button>
<button>сохранить</button>
</form>
```

При нажатии кнопки редактировать убирается disabled и можно изменять данные в инпутах. Но value с этих инпутов на сервер уходят те, что были заранее там написаны(т.е 1 2 3). Может как то можно передать измененные значения (т.е. не А Б В, а например А12 Б21 В33) в php-обработчик?

Comment: можно - поставить инпутам атрибуты `name`

Comment: стоят, я просто для краткости не писал их.

Comment: что еще Вы не написали "для краткости"?

Comment: Теперь есть name... Так может кто все-таки подскажет как передать в обработчик не 1,2,3 а свои значения(когда отключаешь disable)

Comment: приведите Ваши html и javascript *полностью*

Comment: Полностью не нужно. Нужно [mcve]

Comment: Покажите, как Вы передаете данные на сервер. Случайно, значения не из атрибутов `value` считываются?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qghzbeL1/1/                 чтобы я не писал в инпутах на сервер уходят значения из value, а не те которые я туда ввел.

Comment: Приведенный Вами код вообще не отправляет данные на сервер. Последний раз спрашиваю, код будет? Или закрывать вопрос?

Comment: Никаких проблем быть не должно. Передаваться должны именно новые значения. Вы вообще записываете новые значения в БД после их отправки? Или вам это не нужно в вашем случае? Если вы не записываете новые значения в БД, то конечно после отправки формы будут так же отображаться старые значения, но при этом в переменной $_POST на сервер отправятся новые.

Comment: Глубоко извиняюсь, была глупейшая синтаксическая ошибка. Данные просто не перезаписывались из-за нее.